# Is possible to make django translations from a db?

Tags: python, django, translation

I'm new with Django, and i know that with i18 you can translate from a file.
But I want to edit this file later, and add content as a normal user.

Is possible to make translations from a Database?

Comment: Then it's not really i18n, but just normal dynamic content…?!

Comment: @deceze Basically... yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't provide database translation as part of its i18n app. you can use something like [`django-modeltranslation`](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) to manage object translation from the admin and then displaying them in your views or API.